# Custom Controls preventing standard controls from appearing in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a custom Button for use in my WinForms applicationusing the followng little class

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

I'm simply looking to make my application cusomizeable so that I only need change button colors (and in due course other controls) in one place, and that change is reflected throughout the whole application.

After creating the custom button using the above code I set about replacing all standard System.Windows.Forms.Buttons() with MyNamespace.MyButton().  However, whilst the new buttons all appear changed on the screen, other controls like text boxes (which I have not modified) simply are not rendered on the screen at all.  However if I click and drag a window in my application then all of the missing controls suddenly appear.

I have no idea what is causing this.  Can anyone advise me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be "setting" the backcolor property in a paint event, that can cause a constant refreshing of the screen.

One option is to try setting the property in the constructor instead:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
  public MyButton() {
    this.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
  }
}
```

In order to ignore the serialized BackColor property of the control, you can try to change your button class to something like this:

```
public class MyButton : Button {
  private Color myColor = Color.ForestGreen;

  public MyButton() {
    base.BackColor = myColor;
  }

  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
  public new Color BackColor {
    get { return myColor; }
    set { // do nothing 
    }
  }

}
```

This button control will effectively ignore the BackColor property in the designer.  If you want to change the color of all of your buttons, you just have to change your myColor value in code and rebuild.

Comment: Done this - but now the color doesnt change at all from that set in Visual Studio's UI

Comment: @PJW Setting the BackColor in the constructor just sets the default color of the button.  It's still being serialized by the designer so it's remembering the last backcolor value that was set.  It's not clear from your post what you are intending to do with this code.  You need to explain what "color doesn't change...set in...UI" means.  You haven't shared what "property" you are setting.

Comment: If I replace Forest Green in the above code it makes no difference.  The backcolor of the Buttons is still Cyan because thats what I originally set them to in the Visual Studio properties window.  Im looking for a way to set the colors via code so that I only need to change the color in one place to change the back color of ALL buttons in the application.  But if I have to manually go through Visual Studio's properties for every button and change the back color there then I'm not achieving anything.

Comment: @PJW Update post with an example of what I think you are trying to accomplish.